# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not readable on type java.lang.Boolean

Tags: jsp, boolean, el, propertynotfoundexception

I have a class which looks something like this:

```
public class ScoreDefinition {

    protected Boolean primary;

    public Boolean isPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(Boolean value) {
        this.primary = value;
    }

}
```

I am trying to access its `primary` property in EL like this:

```
<c:forEach var="score" items="${scores}">
    <input type="checkbox"
           value="${score.primary}"
           name="someName"
           class="textField"/>
</c:forEach>
```

But I am getting the exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'primary' not readable on type java.lang.Boolean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.read(BeanELResolver.java:280)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperty.access$000(BeanELResolver.java:230)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:81)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:54)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:123)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:938)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administer.projectBlocks_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f2(projectBlocks_jsp.java:806)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administer.projectBlocks_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f2(projectBlocks_jsp.java:709)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administer.projectBlocks_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(projectBlocks_jsp.java:245)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.administer.projectBlocks_jsp._jspService(projectBlocks_jsp.java:150)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.groupgti.webclient.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.groupgti.webclient.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I can not change this class because it is generated from WSDL file. So the question is how can I get around this issue not using any custom EL functions to convert the `Boolean` into `String` or not converting this object to mine? Is it possible to somehow read this property in the EL without any other modifications?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `is` prefix is for `boolean` only, not for `Boolean`.

You have 2 options:

1. Use `boolean` instead of `Boolean`.
2. Or, rename method `isPrimary()` to `getPrimary()`.

As to [JAXB blunder](http://www.mojavelinux.com/blog/archives/2006/09/the_great_jaxb_api_blunder/) of autogenerating the wrong method, you need to upgrade to at least JAXB 2.1.13 or to add `-B-enableIntrospection` to the wsimport call as per this [JAXB documentation](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html).

#### See also:

- [JavaBeans specification - Chapter 8.3.2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html)
- [How does Java expression language resolve boolean attributes? (in JSF 1.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3236929/how-does-java-expression-language-resolve-boolean-attributes-in-jsf-1-2/)
- [JSF 2 checkboxes and boolean getters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157037/jsf-2-checkboxes-and-boolean-getters)

Comment: I can't rename it, the class is automatically generated, I can't change it. So does this means that I have to implement some work around my self?

Comment: Can you add your own method?

Comment: I don't do Spring, but if I guess it right and it's JAXB who did the autogeneration, see updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, it is JAXB generating this. OK I'll add this. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can use a call directly to method **score.isPrimary()** like this:

```
<c:forEach var="score" items="${scores}">
<input type="checkbox"
       value="${score.isPrimary()}"
       name="someName"
       class="textField"/>
</c:forEach>
```